# How to copy an in use dictionary with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading

I've made a mouse track script (just as a challenge, nothing special) that's updating quite a few times per second, but the one big flaw is that whenever it saves, even though it's in a different thread, the whole script pauses due to the cpu usage of pickling it all.

I decided to try use multiprocessing to get around this problem, as in copy this data into a separate process and then do whatever there. My setup was I'd call the thread as normal, but then that would call the process, and the process would feed back to the thread its status through `Queue` (which would then be printed).

The problem I kept hitting was it'd complain about the dictionary size changing whenever I moved the mouse during the saving. I found this was actually due to it pickling the data before it got sent to the new process, and the pickling didn't like the size changing. I tried `deepcopy` and that also didn't like the size changing, so I wrote my own code to manually copy it in a way where it didn't matter if size didn't change, but it was ridiculously slow, as in with my 100mb file, it wasn't showing any signs of completion after 5 minutes.

How should I get around this problem? Basically, given a large dictionary containing other dictionaries and stuff that is being updated many times per second, how do I get it pickled in a reasonable time ready for saving without affecting the main process?

Comment: It seems to me that the mouse tracker should be a source of data that feeds a few primatives into a `Queue`, and then another process listens on the other end to maintain your data structure.  Then temporarily stop listening to the queue when you need to save your data.  Is there a reason that the mouse tracker needs to have access to then entire data structure?

Comment: Hmm, that's quite a nice idea, I'm new to multiprocessing but it doesn't sound too hard. Could a queue handle 60 inputs per second easily (maybe as dictionaries since I'm tracking movement, clicks, and key presses), or should I try group it up and send every second or so?

Comment: Are you keeping track of the mouse's current position or an entire history of postions?  If a history of positions could you track it separately in its own file.  You could open a text file for appending, and then write each new position with a timestamp.

Comment: You shouldn't have any trouble sending 60 updates per second through a queue.

Comment: The movement is stored in a dict of coordinates, and each movement is incremented by 1 (I'll calculate the line between the two frames and write that number to each one of those pixels), to allow me to fade out older coordinates. Once it hits a point it'll crush everything down to stop the numbers getting too out of hand though. I did consider a history of positions but I'd like this to not get too large even if you run it for a month :)   Here's a couple of days worth: http://i.imgur.com/8TwXXlA.jpg

Comment: You can dump to the queue as frequently as you like.  Your listener can process the items in the queue much less frequently.  The queue is your buffer that lets you do the rest of the work at slower pace in chunks.

Comment: I guess if it can cope alright I'll just send it once per frame then, the loop got a bit messy with reading inputs then processing them straight after, so just sending the inputs at the end of each loop would look an awful lot neater haha. Thanks for the help :)